# Custom Field to change task dependend priority - jira

Tags: java, jira

I want to create Custom field. Value o this custom field will be priority of new task dependent priority. But there is a problem how to do this? Field Issue priority doesn't see my custom field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugins like Universal Plugin and set the value of the priority based on another field. On the workflow:

Post Functions > Universal Post Function.

And then:

Choose Post Function to Execute > Copy Value From Other Field.

There, you can select the custom field and copy it to the priority field of the new task.

You can check the documentation here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/UPM/Universal+Plugin+Manager+Documentation;jsessionid=8DDEA826FBA67177206606AC89D1030A.node3

Comment: I cant copy value to priority CF. I can only copy from priority.

Comment: What do you mean you can't? JIRA does not allow you? It does allow me.

Comment: Yea, JIRA doesn't allow for that.